# Caused by: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: A SOAP 1.2 message is not valid when sent to a SOAP 1.1 only endpoint

Tags: cxf

I don't know what I changed anymore :(... But I have ended up with this exception which I don't seem to solve:

```
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: A SOAP 1.2 message is not valid when sent to a SOAP 1.1 only endpoint.
```

I am using CXF 2.7.4 and have the classes generated from the wsdl.
I am using the MTOM  and WSS4JOutInterceptor for signing outgoing messages.

The wsdl contains things like:

```
<wsdl:definitions ... xmlns:soap11="http ... >
<soap11:binding 
<soap11:operation 
soap11:address
```

So that all sound like soap 1.1, but somehow soap 1.2 is being used in the client for the created message.
I have added this in my jaxws client config, but it had no effect.

```
<jaxws:binding>
        <soap:soapBinding version="1.1"/> 
</jaxws:binding>
```

Why does CXF try to use soap 1.2 at all?

Please some advice on how to solve this?
- Ed

Answer (score 2):

I think it is because incoming message is in SOAP1.2 format.
See if it contains references to namespace http://www.w3.org/2003/05